# Is there something like a Dirac sea for bosons?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum

The infinitely negative energy density that we find if we use a non-normal ordered Hamiltonian can be understood as a result of the [Dirac sea](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/55508/does-diracs-idea-of-filled-negative-energy-states-make-sense). Moreover, we only find an infinitely *negative* energy density for fermions as a result of the anticommutation relations:

$$H = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} E_p \left(a_p^\dagger a_p - \frac12\{a_p,a_p^\dagger\}\right),$$
where the second term is an infinitely large constant.

In contrast, for bosons we find if we use a non-normal ordered Hamiltonian an infinitely *positive* energy density:

$$H = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} E_p \left(a_p^\dagger a_p + \frac12[a_p,a_p^\dagger]\right),$$
where again the second term is an infinitely large constant.

*Is it possible to explain this through a similar idea as the Dirac sea does it for fermions?*

PS: One obvious problem is that there is no exclusion principle for bosons. However, even for fermions the exclusion principle alone is not sufficient, to quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_sea)

> [the] Pauli exclusion does not definitively mean that a filled Dirac sea cannot accept more electrons, since, as Hilbert elucidated, a sea of infinite extent can accept new particles even if it is filled.

Comment: The Dirac sea is a flawed concept.

Comment: @my2cts For discussions on the modern interpretation of the Dirac sea, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/515306/ . You seem to be on a personal crusade against the Dirac sea. But this is really not the point of this question. Let's imagine the Dirac sea is an analogy to illustrate the infinite charge and infinite negative energy of the fermionic ground state. Is there are similar idea that illustrates the bosonic ground state?

Comment: @my2cts see also https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/55540/37286